# Typo3 Bootstrap Package 7.1 / missing option "Pic in Text" / "Bild im Text"

Tags: typo3

since updating Bootstrap package to 7.1 we miss the option to have the textflow around our pictures.

[image: Picture Alignment]

is there a way to reactivate this feature..

regards
Leo

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `/Configuration/PageTS/TCEFORM.txt` :

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.imageorient.removeItems = 1,2,9,10,17,18
```

I think you could restore the values you want by overriding this setting.

Comment: Hello - I removed it by adding a comment : #removeItems = 1,2,9,10,17,18 
but it is still the same behavior ..

Comment: I don't know where else to look... did you clear the cache? Can you look at the page tsconfig loaded configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the availability of these options you need to do a matching rendering. as the rendering of textflow around other objects can be very complicated with responsive layouts, those options probably are disabled on purpose as the responsive rendering would be very complicated and was removed from the templates.
Feel free to enable the options and a good rendering and make a pull request to the package.